# Should i be able to set the current pose for amcl?

Tags: ros, navigation, pose, rviz, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In rviz i can click '2d pose estimate' and it'll say:
[ INFO] [1300880777.184874919]: Setting pose: 52.773 -17.701 3.132 [frame=/odom]

or something. But it won't actually move the estimates that amcl is providing.

Additionally, i don't see a published service or subscribed topic for this in amcl beyond the 'initial' pose. Do i need to change the initial pose and somehow restart amcl?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9540/should-i-be-able-to-set-the-current-pose-for-amcl?/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2011-03-23

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-03-28**:
and the 2d pose esstimate topic is set to "initialpose"

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-03-28**:
Fixed frame is set to /odom currently.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-23**:
What is your "fixed frame" set to when you do the 2D pose estimate? What topic is set for the "initialpose" topic in rviz?

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-03-23**:
Also, additionally, should I be able to *see* the current pose? rviz suppose 'pose' but not 'PoseWithCovarianceStamped' that amcl outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order for rviz to correctly set the initialpose for AMCL, rviz's fixed frame must be the same as AMCL's map frame.

Change your fixed frame in rviz to `/map` and then your 2D Pose Estimates should work. You can verify that it is working by subscribing to the PoseArray particle cloud output by AMCL - after a successful estimate, a cloud of particles will be centered on the location you indicated.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-03-28**:
Ugh. Seems that my network connection was suspect (I guess the master node couldn't ping the rviz node). -_- your answer was right. thanks!

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-03-28**:
The cloud of particles does not seem to change location when i do a 2D pose estimate in rviz. I have the fixed frame on /map.

**Comment by [ounsworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/7771/ounsworth/) on 2014-06-17**:
Thank you! Running rviz on the same machine as the master fixed it for me!